# computing the Haar measure for O(n) and U(n) groups

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups

My question is about how to compute the **Haar measure** for **O(n)** and **U(n)** groups.

For example, for the conventional parametrization of SO(3) with 3 angels, the Haar measure is

$ dO= cos(\theta_{13})*d\theta_{12}*d\theta_{13}*d\theta_{23}$ .

How one derives this formula? I want to compute the **Haar measure** for both **O(n)** and **U(n)** for general n.

I am a student of **physics** and I am not quite familiar with **Haar measure**.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1365121/1726) for a general description of Haar measure on $O(n)$, and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1365231/1726) for the same thing on $U(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

You might like [these lecture notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m606/haar.pdf). In particular, the second page discusses such calculations.

Comment: thank you for the lecture note, though it doesn't contain what I was looking for explicitly, but it helped a bit. I found nice example in the book "Integral Geometry and Geometric Probability" by L.A. Santalo